# How to make variable type slices

Tags: go

I was learning go by doing some of the problems I have already completed in other languages.

So one of the problem was:-

- Find the sum of the elements in Array
  Arr = [1,2,[7,8,3],1,[3,[2,[4,5]],6]]

I have tried making an interface type array but that also didn't work

```
func ProdSum(prods interface{},sum int ,depth int){
    for id,val:=range prods{
        if isArray(val){    
                ProdSum(val,sum,depth)
        }
    }

}
type arr []interface{}
func main(){
    arra:=arr{5,2,arr{7,-1},3,arr{6,arr{-13,8},4}}
    ProdSum(arra,0,1)
}
```

```sh
Error :

./prodsum.go:16:14: cannot range over prods (type interface {})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) or [type switch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches) to determine if a value is a slice or an integer.  Here's how to do it using a type switch:

```
func sum(value interface{}) int {
    switch value := value.(type) {
    case arr:
        var result int
        for _, v := range value {
            result += sum(v)
        }
        return result
    case int:
        return value
    default:
        panic("type not handled")
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
a := arr{5, 2, arr{7, -1}, 3, arr{6, arr{-13, 8}, 4}}
n := sum(a)
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/V-6SZ_6D1X5).

Answer (score 3):

The way you are declaring and initializing the array is correct, although you don't need the `arr` type.

Without the `arr` type it will look like this:

[Running in Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/2MnniFD4eY3)

```
myArr := []interface{}{1, 2, []int{7, 8, 3}, 1, []interface{}{3, []interface{}{2, []int{4, 5}}, 6}}
```

Now, the specific error you are seeing is not related to your slice declaration. It is related to the function signature of `ProdSum`.

`ProdSum` takes an argument of type `interface{}`- which is not a slice so you cannot iterate over it. You want the argument to have a type of `[]interface{}` (slice of empty interface):

```
func ProdSum(prods []interface{}, sum int, depth int) {
    for itr, prod := range prods {
         // prod has type: interface{}
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that you will need to do [type assertions](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15) when reading the values out of the slice and summing them. You can't add an `interface{}` to anything because (before an assertion to `int`) Go doesn't recognize it as a number.